# Encoder and decoder function

Tags: encoder, decoder

Can anyone explain the function of encoder and decoder with diagram.?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can get quick answers [here](https://www.google.com/?q=encoder+and+decoder).

Comment: I need something short and easy method with diagram. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of encoders/decoders.  A typical encoder takes a signal that is 1 out of N, encodes and it into a smaller number of lines.  A corresponding decoder takes those encoded value, and restores the 1 of N value.

For example, here is a 1 of 9 decoder, which encodes the input into a 4-bit BCD value.  The corresponding decoder takes that BCD value, and restores the 1 of N output:

[image]

Note that there is one more output than input; there is no need for a I0 input since it would "decode" to a BCD value of 0 0 0 0 anyway.  Whereas on the output of the decoder, that is an explicit output for the zero value O0.

A typical chip that performs the encoding function is a [74HCT147](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc147.pdf), and for the decoding part [74HCT154](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT154.pdf).  Note that latter decodes not only to 1 of 10 as shown in my diagram, but 1 of 16 making using of all combinations of the four bits Y0-Y3 as inputs.